# jQuery event when autocomplete suggestions are displayed

Tags: jquery, events, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete with the source being a local array containing names.
I want to know which of these names are being filtered by the autocomplete, and it seems to be more difficult than I thought!
- The search event is not good to me since it is being fired before the filtering happens.
- The open event is not good either since it happens only once. If the user keeps on typing then I don't have the filtered values.

So I don't see an option right now. I must say it feels completely weird to me. I would expect an easy way to grab these values, and hopefully there is.
What am I missing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just use [onKeyUp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp).  That way you can check after every change to the auto-complete suggestions.

Comment: Well you're probably right. The other option I'm considering is to use the callback and to implement the filtering myself...

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned about running the filter twice every time, you can still use the search callback.

```
$("#list").autocomplete({
    source: anArray,
    search: function(event){
        var data = $(event.target).data("autocomplete");
        var result = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(data.options.source, data.term);
    }
});
```